# Showing $2^{n_2} + 3^{n_3}+\cdots+9^{n_9}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I encountered this problem via a friend. He asked me to prove that 
$$ \left\{u: u= \sum_{k=2}^9 k^{n_k} \quad n_k \in \mathbb{Z}  \right\}$$ 
is dense in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I was able to show that $0$ is approachable(can get arbitrarily close to) by numbers of this type. However to proceed ahead, I need to know what operations preserve the structure of these numbers. For instance, to show $m+n\sqrt{2}$ is dense for all integers $m,n$, I used the fact that product of any two numbers in this form yields a number in the same form. My problem is I don't know what pattern to exploit in the given problem.

I appreciate any hints / patterns you can provide. One idea I have been working on is as follows:

If we could partition $2^{n_2}, 3^{n_3},\ldots, 9^{n_9}$ into two parts, one that would determine the integer part, the other that would approximate the fractional part, we would be done.

Comment: I think it is not dense in : $[1/9 + 1/8 + 1/7 + \dots + 1/2 , 1]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that this is true.

First consider the part of the sum involving negative exponents.  The most that this part can be is
$$2^{-1}+\cdots+9^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}+\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}\Bigr)+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=2\ .$$
Now consider the parts with non-negative exponents.  Let $n$ be a positive integer.  For $k=2,\ldots,9$, the number of powers of $k$ in the range from $1$ to $10^n$ is
$$1+\left\lfloor n\frac{\log10}{\log k}\right\rfloor<5n\ .$$
Therefore the number of sums of powers of $2,\ldots,9$ with non-negative exponents, the sum not exceeding $10^n$, is at most $(5n)^8$.  For large $n$ this is very much less than $10^n$; so there will in some cases be gaps of at least $3$ between attainable sums; and from the first part of the argument, these gaps cannot be "bridged" by taking some terms with negative exponents.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried about the gaps. But I thought they would be bridged if we took enough terms. Guess not. This answers my question satisfactorily. Let me wait and see if there are better (cuter) answers. Guess my friend was trying to fool me in advance on April Fool's Day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done. Think of it like this: Suppose you have $u \in \Bbb{R}_+$ and $u_n \to u$ with
$$ u_n = \sum_{k=2}^9 k^{m_k^n} $$

Now each $(u_n)$ is completely characterized by $(m_2^n,...,m_9^n)$. If $u$ is not zero then not all sequences $(m_k^n)_n$ go to $-\infty$, so some of them are bounded, which means that we will have some values repeated an infinity of times. Then we can extract a diagonal sequence such that every $(m_k^n)_n$ which does not go to $-\infty$ is constant. This means that you approximate $u=2^{a_2}+...+9^{a_9}$ where $a_1,...,a_9$ are integers or $-\infty$ (with convention $a^{-\infty}=0$ for $a>1$.)

Obviously not every $u$ can be written in this form.

In the same way you can prove that the colsure of the set you mention is precisely
$$ \{ u =2^{a_1}+...+9^{a_9} : a_i \in \Bbb{Z} \cup \{-\infty\}\} $$

Comment: Although infinity is not allowed as an exponent, I see your point. Give me some time to check.

Comment: I used $a^{-\infty}=0$ to keep notations simple. Of course it is intended to be understood as a limit.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help.